# Why does math.round not round to 2 digits?

Tags: vb.net, math, rounding

Following VB.Net code does not return the expected result:

```
        Dim sum As Single = 535353
        Dim vat As Single = Math.Round(sum * 0.19, 2)
        Dim total As Single = Math.Round(sum + vat, 2)

        Debug.WriteLine(String.Format("sum: {0:c2}, vat: {1:c2}, total: {2:c2}", sum, vat, total))
```

vat is correctly set to *101717.07*, but the result of "total" is *636070.063*.
Why does the last Math.round function returns 3 digits, and the wrong result?

Comment: Can't replicate. I get `sum: $535,353.00, vat: $101,717.10, total: $637,070.10`: https://ideone.com/CMovY8

Comment: Note that `Single` only has 7 digits of precision which is why everything is effectively rounded to the first digit after the decimal

Comment: @DStanley - where did you get '7 digits of precision'?

Comment: Use Double instead of Single.

Comment: @dbasnett https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/system.single?view=netframework-4.8: "A Single value has up to 7 decimal digits of precision, although a maximum of 9 digits is maintained internally"

Comment: @dbasnett Or use `Decimal` or scaled integers if working with money or other fixed-point values.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Try it using Double

```
    Dim sum As Double = 535353
    Dim vat As Double = Math.Round(sum * 0.19, 2)
    Dim total As Double = Math.Round(sum + vat, 2)
    '           sum     535353.0    Double
    '           total   637070.07   Double
    '           vat     101717.07   Double
```

Comment: Do you get the OP's results if you use Single?

Comment: @DStanley - Did not try it since Math.Round returns double.